# .exe window exit after

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I used visual studio 2012 and this is my first time to use that. I started wth

<kbd>NEW</kbd>→<kbd>Project-Empty</kbd>→<kbd>Project-source</kbd>then<kbd>files-add</kbd>→<kbd>new items-Cpp file</kbd> and input the following codes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int cents;
    int dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;

    cout << "Enter total cents: ";
    cin >> cents;

    dollars = cents / 100;
    cents = cents - dollars*100;
    quarters = cents / 25;
    cents = cents - quarters*25;
    dimes = cents / 10;
    cents = cents - dimes*10;
    nickels = cents / 5;
    cents = cents - nickels*5;
    pennies = cents;  

    cout << "This corresponds to "
         << dollars << " dollars, "
         << quarters << " quarters, "
         << dimes << " dimes, "
         << nickels << " nickels, and "
         << pennies << " pennies.\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I want to make a program to break down cents into `dollars`, `quarters`, `nickels`, `dimes` and `pennies`, the `.exe` window was successfully formed but after I entered  the number of cents I want to convert the window disappeared. breakpoint or system("pause") seems don't work. And here is the messages:

```
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe'. Symbols loaded. 'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded. The thread 0xe24 has exited with code -1073741749 (0xc000004b). The program '[7476] Project2.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

How can I keep the `.exe` window and see the result?

Comment: "breakpoint or system("pause") seems don't work."  You must have done something wrong, because both of those should work fine.

Comment: @MooingDuck: He's pausing *before* writing any output, which obviously won't work. His code doesn't actually write anything until it returns from `main`.

Answer (score 1):

The return code `0xc000013a` from the program suggests that CTRL-C was pressed, causing the program to exit. Did you press CTRL-C perchance?

What happens if you hard-code the number of cents (e.g. say to 1999), instead of prompting the user to enter a number? Does it work correctly then?

What happens if you add a "cin >> cents;" *after* the cout statement showing the calculated values?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to write console programs, you should run them from a console. If you want to write a program to run from a GUI, write a GUI program.

The reason `system("pause")` didn't work is that you never do `cout.flush();` or `cout << endl;`. Pausing before you actually produce output won't help.

Comment: didn't know where the downvotes come from,but still didn't work with cout.flush(); or cout << endl, may you tell me where do I insert them?

Comment: @RandyHuang: Paste the code that didn't work. The simplest solution is to replace `\n\n";` with `" << endl << endl;`. Then run **all** your tests again until you understand what effect that had.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+
<kbd>F5</kbd> to run your program without debugging tools.

Comment: tried, but the window still interrupted after I input the number and didn't show the output

Comment: @RandyHuang: If you retested without the fix I gave you, you're wasting your time.